How to change YITH subscription reccuring price on WooCommerce cart
I am doing custom coding for adding a product to the cart with a custom price ( Subscription Product type from YITH ) based on a condition ( qty of sensors products in the cart ).
Now I can edit the initial price with the below hook ( First month period ) the problem is that the recurring price still gets the default price, not the one I determine on the hook.
so is there a way to edit the recurring price for the YITH Subscription plugin
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_product_to_cart_on_update');

function add_product_to_cart_on_update($cart)
{
    if (is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }
    
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;
    
    $product_id_to_add = get_field('subscription_product', 'option');

    // $product_id_to_add = 767; // The product ID to add
    $qty = 0;
    $found = false;
    $product_cart_key_to_add = '';

    $sensor_products = array();

    // Loop through the cart to gather data
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $product_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
        $is_sensor_product = get_post_meta($product_id, '_sensor_product', true);

        if ($is_sensor_product === 'yes') {
            $sensor_products[$cart_item_key]['id'] = $product_id;
            $sensor_products[$cart_item_key]['qty'] = $product_qty;
        }

        if ($product_id_to_add == $product_id) {
            $found = true;
            $product_cart_key_to_add = $cart_item_key;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the total quantity of sensor products
    foreach ($sensor_products as $sensor_p) {
        $qty += $sensor_p['qty'];
    }

    // Get the product object
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id_to_add);
    
    $sale_qty = get_field('number_of_sensors', 'option');

    if ( $sale_qty != null && $qty < $sale_qty && $found) {
        // Set the price to the regular price if quantity is less than 5
        $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $cart->set_quantity($product_cart_key_to_add, $qty);
        $cart->get_cart_item($product_cart_key_to_add)['data']->set_price($regular_price);
    } elseif (!$found) {
        // Add the product with the default WooCommerce price handling
        $cart_item_key = $cart->add_to_cart($product_id_to_add, $qty);
        $product_cart_key_to_add = $cart_item_key;
        $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $cart->get_cart_item($product_cart_key_to_add)['data']->set_price($regular_price);
    } else {
        // If quantity is 5 or more, keep the sale price by default
        $cart_item_key = $cart->add_to_cart($product_id_to_add, $qty);
    }
}


First, try to define a higher hook priority like add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_product_to_cart_on_update', 100, 1 );, as YITH Subscription uses this hook in includes/class.ywsbs-subscription-cart.phpfile.

Yes, I have noticed this and fixed it and updated the code above, but could you give me an example of using what in that class class.ywsbs-subscription-cart  that achieve my goal

There is no such example… the class YWSBS_Subscription_Cart handle YITH subscription product in cart: Look at the comments in the __construct function that describe processes by groups of hooked functions.
